# How to receive MPEG-TS multicast from Windows

Tags: windows, multicast, wmp, mpeg

We currently have a system with live video encoded to an MPEG-TS multicast stream, being received by televisions with STBs. In addition to televisions we'd like to embed the video in our Windows application.

I know that VLC will receive the stream, but would prefer both a solution that I can embed in an existing application without playing window moving games, and one without licensing problem. I realize that likely means that I'm not looking at a free solution, that's fine, within reason.

Anyone know of a good product for this? Either something easy to use, or a plug-in for WMP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to develop a simple `DirectShow` filter that listens on a given port and just passes down every packet it had received.

I don't have a sample handy, but it's really simple, several hundreds lines of code.

Then you just connect this filter to an `MPEG2 Demultiplexer` capable of decoding `transport stream`.

`NVidia` and `Elecard` come to mind first, though the former one does not connect under debugger.

Then you connect the `demultiplexer` to the `decoder` and finally to the `renderer`.

The demultiplexers and decoders handle the live stream issues well, you just capture the `UDP` packets and send down to them.

Due to licensing issues, `MPEG2` decoders cannot be free (`ffmpeg` and `VLC` violate the license), so you'll have to buy the decoder.

Visit [**http://elecard.com**](http://elecard.com/), they have a nice range of `MPEG2` products.

Comment: The Elecard MPEG2 plugin did exactly what I need. Took a bit of doc reading to get that I needed to use the elecard: protocol in order to do proper RTP and not the WMP style RTP. Only question is if it's for commercial use is it more or less than $25 per?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Quassnoi's answer...

You might check out the [Haali Media Splitter](http://haali.cs.msu.ru/mkv/) to act as a "MPEG2 Demultiplexer."  This is a filter that just pulls the compressed video and sound out of the transport stream, so I'm guessing it doesn't have any licensing issues.  Most PCs with a DVD player on them already have a licensed DirectShow MPEG2 decoder, so you can probably just use one that's already installed (or purchase a license from a place like elecard if you really want to be safe).

As you are developing your DirectShow application, you might find [Monogram GraphStudio](http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/tools/monogram-graphstudio/) to be a helpful tool in designing the filter chains.

Comment: These are running XP embedded, and don't have MPEG2. I was trying to avoid going down the filter writing route, I've done it before, but I'd rather buy one. Thanks for a link to the next filter down the chain if I need to do it that way though.